# Implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivatives of

$(1+xy)^3 =yx^{-1} $

I tried this and stuck

$3(1+xy)^2 (0+ x(\frac{dy}{dx}) + y ) = -yx^{-2} + (x^{-1} \frac{dy}{dx} ) $

$\frac{dy}{dx} (x+y-x^{-1}) = -yx^{-2} - 3(1+xy)^2 $

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-yx^2-3(1+xy)^2}{x+y-x^{-1}} $

I'm not quite sure how to simplify it to achieve the final answer -

$\frac{-y(3x^2(1+xy)^2+1}{x(3x^2(1+xy)^2-1} $

Comment: take logarithm at both sides D: of your equation

Comment: @JoseGarcia is there anyway to avoid using logarithm for this ? Because I haven't learnt it and I need to use the basic rules to solve this

Comment: You have a mistake in the third equation ... Ping me, if you want some help.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the $d$ operator to both sides as I think you have done we have
$$
3(1+xy)^2(y+xy')=y'\frac{1}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}\implies 3y(1+xy)^2+3x(1+xy)^2y'=y'\frac{1}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}
$$
which we can solve for $y'$ as follows
$$
y'(\frac{1}{x}-3x(1+xy)^2)=3y(1+xy)^2+\frac{y}{x^2}\\
\implies y'=\frac{3y(1+xy)^2+\frac{y}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x}-3x(1+xy)^2}=
\frac{3x^2y(1+xy)^2+y}{x-3x^3(1+xy)^2}
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand the second line in the first part . How did the 3y and 3x appear and how (y+xy') become (1+xy)^2

Comment: He is applying the chain rule to take $$\frac{d}{dx}(1+xy)^3.$$ If we write $$f(x,y)=1+xy$$ then we have $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x,y))^3=3(f(x,y))^2\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}x+\frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}y\right).$$ Note that $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=y$$ and $$\frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)=x$$ (check this for yourself), so we get $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x,y))^3=3(1+xy)^2(y+xy').$$ From here, he distributes over the addition in the second parentheses to get $$3(1+xy)^2y+3(1+xy)^2xy'.$$ He just rearranged this to look like above: $$3y(1+xy)^2+3x(1+xy)^2y'.$$